# The Expectation in terms of probability

Tags: probability

let the independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ takes values in the range $\{1,...,n\}$

- Calculate the Expectation of $X$ in terms of $P(X \geqslant k)$.

Indeed,

note that $$\{X=k\}=\{X\geq k\}\cup  \{X<k  \}$$ then
$$P\{X=k\}=P\{X\geq k\}+P\{X<k  \}$$
$$P\{X=k\}=P\{X\geq k\}+1-P\{X \geq k+1\}$$
$$E[x]=\sum_{k=1}^{n}kP\{X\geq k\}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}k1-\sum_{k=1}^{n}kP\{X \geq k+1\} $$

Comment: What you wrote doesn't make any sense at all.  Suppose $n = 3$ and furthermore, suppose $\Pr[X = 1] = \Pr[X = 2] = \Pr[X = 3] = \frac{1}{3}$.  Then $\Pr[X \ge 2] = \frac{2}{3}$ and $\Pr[X < 2] = \frac{1}{3}$, and $\Pr[X = 2] \ne \Pr[X \ge 2] + \Pr[X < 2]$.

Answer (score 4):

$\begin{align}
p(1)+p(2)+p(3)+&... =P(X\ge 1)\\
p(2)+p(3)+&...=P(X\ge 2) \\
p(3)+&...=P(X\ge 3)  \\
\end{align}\\$

etc.

Now add up each column.